# change remote notification time on screen

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have in my app a video chat.
And for the incoming call i'm using remote push notifications.
Is there a way to leave the notification on screen for a longer time then the default?
I need it to be on screen for about 20 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: No. (filling text for reaching min characters)

Comment: So is there any different way to have a incoming call notification appear on screen?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could send multiple notifications short after each other.